# how to add all scores from a database

Tags: php, mysql, sum

im making a rankings sysem where you get all scores from the daabse according to your country.

```
$q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE country='USA'");
while($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
$score = $row['score'];
}
```

I want to add each piece of score. Like add them all and get the total score from a country.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(score) FROM ...`

Comment: SELECT SUM(score) FROM scores WHERE country='USA'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT SUM(score) FROM scores WHERE country = 'USA'
```

In the query above, you are SUMming up the column restricted by the `country`

Here's a piece of code that will get you what you desire:

```
$q = $con->query("SELECT SUM(score) as total FROM scores WHERE country='USA'");
while($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    $score = $row['total'];
}
```

Comment: What is the output of all the scores. Like $scores = Total score.

Comment: That's a different question. Just accept the answer and make another question. Or even better: check a bit of google.instead of making people work for you.

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. Love u so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
SELECT SUM(score) FROM scores GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data into array. Each element of the array will than contain a single row of data. You can than access the array in different ways.

```
$scores = array();
$q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE country='USA'");
while($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    $scores[] = $row['score'];
}

// Process $scores filled with data
print_r($scores); // This prints content of an array

// You can iterate the array like this:
$sum = 0;
foreach ($scores as $key => $value) {
    $sum += $value["amount"]; // replace 'amount' with proper column name
    echo "Under index " . $key . " is this score: " . $value . "\n";
}

echo "Total sum is: " . $sum;
```

If you want to add all scores, just remove WHERE condition from the query:

```
$q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM scores");
```

Comment: I actually wanted to add all the scores.

Comment: I still cant add all the scores from a country using ur method. Give an in depth explanation pls.

Comment: Its hard to work with array, thanks for helping though. The person below answered my question.

Comment: `count(array)` does not *sum* the array's contents!

Comment: @deceze Youre right, didn't notice there was a sum request in the question. Removed that line.

Comment: So now you're still not summing the scores at all.

Comment: @deceze Yes, forgot to put it there...been a little bussy lately...now it's there.